# How does task scheduler plugin implements cron that is not dependent on page load request?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-cron, cron

I have been looking at [task scheduler Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/task-scheduler/) that claims to run cron task at a fixed interval without depending on page load request. Can anyone help me understand how it does the same?

Comment: 1. impossible. 2 Any reason not to ask the author, or look at the code?